# RxJava: Specifying maximum concurrency for a list of Completables

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm trying to query an API that provides me with a list of files to download (as follows). I then proceed to download these files while also re-querying the API for anything that may have been missed in the initial call.

`Completable#mergeDelayError(Iterable<? extends CompletableSource> sources)` is used to ensure I can perform multiple tasks in parallel and get notified when everything has been completed.

```
fun fetchAndDownload(details: List<String>): Completable = 
    exampleApi.fetchPackages(details) // This is a Single
        .flatMapCompletable { (results, retry) -> 
            val completables = mutableListOf<Completable>()
            results.mapTo(completables) { value ->
                exampleApi.download(value).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            }

            if (retry.isNotEmpty()) { 
                completables += fetchAndDownload(retry)
                    .delay(3L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            }
            Completable.mergeDelayError(completables)
        }
```

However, this implementation has the possibility of overwhelming the network and/or thread count by executing too many things at once. I am therefore wondering what the best approach would be to limit the number of `completables` that are running at once.

I am aware of `Completable#mergeDelayError(Publisher<? extends CompletableSource> sources, int maxConcurrency)` but am not sure how to convert my `List<Completable>` to the required `Publisher`. An alternative solution is to provide a custom `Scheduler` that has a maximum thread count, but I am also not sure how to provide such a `Schduler` (that I can clean and discard when it is no longer needed).

Comment: Use Flowable.fromIterable for the conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use `Floable.fromIterable` to convert the `List` of `Completable` to a `Publisher`.

This will allow for the use of `Completable#mergeDelayError(Publisher<? extends CompletableSource> sources, int maxConcurrency)`

Answer (score 2):

You can just use **flatMap** with **maxConcurrent** value, and then make your pipeline run asyncroniously.

```
  @Test
    public void asyncFlatMapWithMaxConcurrent() {
        Observable.from(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
                .flatMap(value -> Observable.just(value)
                        .map(number -> {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                                System.out.println(String.format("Value %s in Thread execution:%s",number, Thread.currentThread().getName()));
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return number;
                        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                        , 2)//This is the max concurrenrt
        .subscribe();
        new TestSubscriber()
                .awaitTerminalEvent(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    }
```

If you see as a second argument after the function of the flatMap, we pass a value 2 which is the max number of concurrent threads that can run for that flatMap

You can see the example and some more here.

https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/transforming/ObservableFlatMap.java